# Ember 1.11 lookup route:application oddity when testing

Tags: ember.js

In Ember 1.10, the following code works:

```
App.__container__.lookup('route:application')
```

In Ember 1.11, it returns `undefined`.

When my test is run in isolation, it works, so my issue has to be something to do with clean up of code. I'm using:

```
module("Integration App Test", {
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});
```

But that doesn't seem to be working correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a bug with `App.reset()` in Ember 1.11. See [this GitHub issue for more details](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10310#issuecomment-89867978).